# How to achieve color tint in HTML5 target?

Tags: haxe, openfl

As I am targeting HTML5, I need to change the color tint, currently using bitmap.draw with color transform filter would lead to a cropped result, as the same code has worked perfectly on flash target.

But is there other way to change color tint for a sprite in HTML5? openFL can expose SpriteDOM for each element on the canvas, how useful would this be to use javascript to change tint color for SpriteDOM ?

Or maybe using `RenderSession` ?

Comment: If you are working with a canvas, you could use the [globalCompositeOperation Mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Compositing)

Comment: But I only have one Canvas, all sprites are in the same canvas, and I need to change tint per Sprite, is the link you've sent still an option?

Comment: Sure, just change the Composition Mode after each sprite.

Comment: I am sorry, can you please write a little example as an answer or a gist, I am just new to this composite concept

Comment: Sure, here are 2 Demos: [Composition Mode](https://jsfiddle.net/kvcox374/) and [Color Key Shifting](http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/2d7ZN/)

Comment: Thank you very much